# Give two different data frame inputs to PySpark UDF and save output in new data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use python function using PySpark data frame. I need to give two data frames at input and would like to store the results in the another data frame.

Python function I want to use:

```py
@udf(StringType())    
def fuzz_ratio(df1, df2):
    return np.vectorize(fuzz.token_sort_ratio(df1, df2))
```

This is how I am trying to use the above function:

```py
result_df.withcolumn("VAL", fuzz_ratio(col(df1.VAL), col(df2.VAL)))
```

`df1` and `df2` are inputs. `VAL` columns of both these data frame contain the values I need to input to the function `fuzz_ratio`. The output should be saved in `VAL` column of `result_df`.

Example:

[image]

The VAL is the column name in all the dataframes. `df1` and `df2` column VAL is of string type.

Comment: `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` works with strings. But you provided dataframes... Please explain, what you meant. Do you have specific string columns in mind? In such case you will have to join both dataframes on some column first. Please explain.

Comment: Yes, it takes strings. But if you give it two columns (ofcourse of type string) then it will give ratio of each record pair. Tested this thing with Pandas it works.

Comment: So are both columns in the same dataframe? If not, then you need to join both dataframes. In Pandas, you can do row-by-row calculations, because the row order is fixed. In Spark, row order is not fixed, so you need to join the dataframes first, to make both strings stay in the same row.

Comment: I can combine them so that both VAL columns are side by side (inner join) and then send them are separate columns to the function. That looks like a good way to sort it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you move both columns to the same dataframe, something like the following [**`pandas_udf`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) could be used. `pandas_udf` is vectorized for performance. It's not the same as regular Spark `udf`.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df = spark.createDataFrame([('danial khilji', 'danial'), ('a','as',)], ['col1', 'col2'])
df.show()
# +-------------+------+
# |         col1|  col2|
# +-------------+------+
# |danial khilji|danial|
# |            a|    as|
# +-------------+------+
```

Script:

```py
@F.pandas_udf('long')
def fuzz_ratio(c1: pd.Series, c2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.concat([c1, c2], axis=1).apply(lambda x: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)

df.withColumn('fuzz_ratio', fuzz_ratio('col1', 'col2')).show()
# +-------------+------+----------+
# |         col1|  col2|fuzz_ratio|
# +-------------+------+----------+
# |danial khilji|danial|        63|
# |            a|    as|        67|
# +-------------+------+----------+
```